# extraction of text from HTML web pages using java

Tags: java, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Text extraction with java html parsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2609948/text-extraction-with-java-html-parsers)

I m new to java and is trying to program an algorithm for web page classification. I want to know how to extract text from HTML web pages in java. Would be of great help if I could get a base idea of what to do.

Thanks
Archana

Comment: Also a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386107/text-extraction-from-html-java & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3036638/how-to-extract-web-page-textual-content-in-java

Answer (score 0):

You could turn to already existing HTML parsing tools, such as
JSOUP, once you obtained the raw HTML String.

look here for a comparison
[What are the pros and cons of the leading Java HTML parsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3152138/what-are-the-pros-and-cons-of-the-leading-java-html-parsers/3154281#3154281)

Also find a quick example of what you could easily extract from an HTML page using JSOUP and the CSS selectors
http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/example-list-links

Comment: hey guys..thnx a lot 4 da suggestions..finally using jsoup and it works!!

Answer (score 0):

I use [Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) to convert an HTML document to text.  The code to get the text is pretty simple:

```
    Source source = new Source(html);
    Renderer renderer = source.getRenderer();
    String text = renderer.toString();
```

There are some options you can set on the renderer to adjust the texification, like:

```
renderer.setIncludeHyperlinkURLs(false);
```

Answer (score -1):

@Codemwnci's answer helps you download the HTML page.

If you're looking for a way to separate HTML markup tags from content, you should use an HTML parser.

Comment: -1 for suggesting regular expressions to parse HTML.

Comment: @Richard, I agree that regular expressions will probably not be the best choice, but I also suggested using a parser, I actually edited my response and reordered the suggestions after your -1. The reason for suggesting regular expressions is cases like only getting the text from a certain HTML tag.